# ORACLE SQL Pivot Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pivot a sql result. I need to do this all in the one query. The below is telling me invalid identifier for header_id. I am using an Oracle database.

Code

```
Select * From (
select ppd.group_id,g.group_name, ct.type_desc,ht.hos_cat_descr
from item_history ih, item ci, contract ppd, 
header ch, group g, cd_std_type ct, cd_hos h, 
cd_std_hospital_cat ht
where ih.item_id = ci.item_id
and ih.header_id = ch.header_id
and ci.hos_id = h.hos_id
and ih.item_id = ci.item_id
and ch.user_no = ppd.user_no
and ppd.group_id = g.group_id
and ch.header_type = ct.header_type_id
and ci.hos_id = h.hos_id
and h.cat_id = ht.cat_id
)
Pivot
(
count(distinct header_id) as Volume
For hos_cat_descr IN ('A')
)
```

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: The policy where I work is to use where clauses

Comment: . . That is sad, very sad.

Comment: Your inner query's select list doesn't have `header_id`...?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole how do I actually specify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner query doesn't have `header_id` in its projection, so the pivot clause doesn't have that column available to use. You need to add it, either as:

```
Select * From (
select ppd.group_id,g.group_name, ct.type_desc,ht.hos_cat_descr,ih.header_id
---------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
from ...
)
Pivot
(
count(distinct header_id) as Volume
For hos_cat_descr IN ('A')
)
```

or:

```
Select * From (
select ppd.group_id,g.group_name, ct.type_desc,ht.hos_cat_descr,ch.header_id
---------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
from ...
)
Pivot
(
count(distinct header_id) as Volume
For hos_cat_descr IN ('A')
)
```

It doesn't really matter which, since those two values must be equal as they are part of a join condition.

You could achieve the same thing with simpler aggregation instead of a pivot, but presumably you are doing more work in the pivot really.

Comment: Thank you for this, yes this was a simpler version (the real issue being my lack of experience with pivots). Can I ask For hos_cat_descr IN ('A') Do I always have to specify the values, or is there a way to inherently take all values that exist in this field?

Comment: You have to specify the values; when the query is parsed the final number of output columns has to be known, so the number of `IN` values must be fixed. And you can't use a subquery within that clause - partly because the values available in the table might change between invocations. You could use a dynamic pivot or an XML pivot, but that gives you other problems.

Comment: @E_McAndrew - [this overview of pivot](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) is quite helpful.